# What is the difference between fight off and fight back?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, definition

Is there a clear distinction between these two phrases? are there any cases they can be used interchangeably? |Thanks.

Comment: You _fight off_ an attacker, but _fight back_ **against** one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **fight someone off** when you fight an attacker enough that *they give up* attacking you. It also suggests they do not succeed in whatever their main goal was. Like if they're trying to steal your purse and you fight them off, then they didn't get your purse.

You **fight *someone* back** when you fight an attacker enough that *they are forced to retreat* in the direction they came from, or enough that *they are forced to keep a minimum distance from you* that prevents them from attacking. This does not imply they have quit attacking, just that they were forced to stop attacking for the moment.

You **fight back (against someone)** when you attack someone who has attacked you previously. It's a retaliatory attack.

Answer (score 2):

To "fight someone off" or to "fight off" is to defend yourself merely to the point that you can flee the fight. This always refers to a physical combat situation.

To "fight someone back" is not something we normally say.

To "fight back" is to defend yourself. It can refer to physical combat, or it can refer to other types of conflicts such as false accusations, legal cases, etc. To fight back also tends to go farther than to "fight off". The goal is to ensure that you eliminate the threat. It does not have to be retaliatory.

Comment: It also suffices to make the attacker stop attacking; you do not have to flee in order to fight them off.